# how to identify the position of the error tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to achieve to get the position of the error tag in DOM. based on the position I need to set the attributes to my code. How to get the generic way of finding the position of the p.error.

Here it is what tried:

Scenario 1:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"> 
    <label> email </label> 
    <p class="error">Please enter E-mail</p>
    <input type="email" value=""> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6"> 
    <label> password </label> 
    <p class="error">Please enter password</p>
    <input type="password" value=""> 
</div>
```

Scenario 2:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"> 
    <label> email </label> 
    <input type="email" value=""> 
    <p class="error">Please enter E-mail</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6"> 
    <label> password </label> 
    <input type="password" value=""> 
    <p class="error">Please enter password</p>
</div>
```

In the scenario 1, the position of the p.error is on the top of the input. and in the scenario 2 it is below to the input field.

Now what is the generic way to find the position, whether it is below or above.

```
previous = $("p.error").prev();
next = $("p.error").next();

previous.on('focusin', function(ev) { });
previous.on('keydown',function(ev) {
    $(this).prev().attr({
        'role': 'xyz',
    });
});
next.on('focusin', function(ev) {
    $(this).prev().attr({
        'role': 'xyz',
    });  
});
```

Comment: Can you just check if the tagName property of previous or next respectively is "input"? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @HAnnesJohansson : Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can check the tagName property of previous and next by doing

```
previous[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input'; // error is after
next[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input'; // error is before
```

Another solution would be to use the input tag as selector in the next() method, like this:

```
$('p.error').next('input').length > 0; // error is before
$('p.error').prev('input').length > 0; // error is after
```